# How to get component's id after clicking on it - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I have an array of objects in *rides-context.js*. In *RidesList.js* I map the data of the array and pass it to the component in order to display it on screen.

```
const RidesList = (props) => {
  const rideCtx = useContext(RidesContext);

  const deleteHandler= () => {
    rideCtx.onDelete(??)
  }
 
  return (
    <ul className={classes.container}>
      {rideCtx.ridesList.map((ride) => (
        <Ride hour={ride.hour} name={ride.name} key={ride.key} id={ride.id} onDelete={deleteHandler}/>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Now I want to delete a component after clicking on it. In order to do so, I have to pass the component's id to the function which is located in *rides-context.js*. How can I get the id of the element that's been clicked?(onDelete is connected to onClick in another file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is to use a closure and pass the id of the `ride` to the `deleteHandler` in the place where this is available. To do so you can pass an anonymous function as the `onDelete` prop, which is gonna be called with the `ride.id` like below:

```
const RidesList = (props) => {
  const rideCtx = useContext(RidesContext);

  const deleteHanlder = (id) => {
    rideCtx.onDelete(id)
  }
 
  return (
    <ul className={classes.container}>
      {rideCtx.ridesList.map((ride) => (
        <Ride hour={ride.hour} name={ride.name} key={ride.key} id={ride.id} onDelete={() => deleteHandler(ride.id)}/>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I haven't known that sth like this will work, I tried different things but didn't come up with this kind of idea